# excel to matlab structure using column names

Tags: matlab, import, structure, names

I have to analyze a data given in Excel format. I will use MATLAB and I want to write a code which automatically creates structure using the column's name.

The columns are formatted as follows:

```
Speed_55m.max  Speed_55m.min  Speed_55m.stdev Speed_55m.value
```

And that 4 pair of names is repeating for different heights.I want to have a loop which reeds the column names and creates a structure.

I have tried the following code:

```
[a,b]=xlsread('PP_RR.xlsx');
for icol=1:size(a,2)
   char(b{icol})=a(:,icol);
end
```

But I received the following error:

```
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is using the file explorer window on the MATLAB home page. Double click on the excel spreadsheet to open the import wizard, select "import as table". MATLAB will automatically create a 'table' data type variable with the same column names as your spreadsheet. If that does not work, convert the .xlsx to a .csv, and it will for sure.